# How do you declare or use variables in web.config

Tags: iis, web-config

Because our web application is using both Entityframework and System.Data.SqlClient, we need to have 2 .
This is very error prone, as you need to make you update both with the same data.

So i wonder if its posible to add variables to the web.config xml?

```html
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Server" value="sql2014" type="variable" />
   <add name="database" value="MyDB" type="variable" />
   <add name="userName" value="sqluser" type="variable" />
   <add name="password" value="kaldsommer" type="variable" />

    <add name="XReport" connectionString="Data Source={Server};Initial Catalog={MyDB};User ID={username};Password={password}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="XEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.XModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.XModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.XModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source{Server};initial catalog={MyDB};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={username};Password={password}&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. On the other hand maintaining 2 connection strings is not that complicated, although I agree it's always best to update things only once ...

Comment: Then post it as a response.

Its is a issue because this is software that we sell and install on a large number of servers. And from experience its easy to do a mistake on one of these.

Comment: It seems your company have ressources so You can probably quickly manage to create some kind of parser taking an original web.config with some kind of variables in it though, and replaces variables by values given as user input to output the final web.config. As I see it such a dev shouldn't take more than a few hours and could even be further improved later. As I write it I realize it is so simple that there should already be a lot of similar tools to find on the web...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pr @Bartude reply in comment.

> FAIK, this is not possible. On the other hand maintaining 2 connection
>   strings is not that complicated, although I agree it's always best to
>   update things only once